# How do I add Eclipse to the launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, eclipse

I'm using the following eclipse.desktop file [1] on the Unity dock but I keep seeing the following error [2] in the ".xsession-errors" file everytime I click the Eclipse icon. Are there any ideas why this is happening?

[1]

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Java IDE
Exec=/bin/sh /home/USERNAME/eclipse/eclipse
Icon=/home/USERNAME/eclipse/icon.png
Categories=Application;Development;Java;IDE
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=0
```

[2]

```
/home/USERNAME/eclipse/eclipse: 5: /home/USERNAME/eclipse/eclipse: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```